# Is ext3cow still being developed?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

Title say's it all, Just wondering if ext3cow is still being developed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not it's not maintained anymore. It went off the radar screen in 2008 and so did the [tools](http://sharesource.org/project/ext3cowtools/) (only the hg source code repo seems to be available).  but that was a separate initiative anyway. The lead developer [Zachary Peterson](http://www.znjp.com/www/home.html) seems to have shifted its interest to other matters.
From Tim Post's (the developer of the tools) own [admission](http://echoreply.us/tech/2008/02/20/new-ext3cow-tools-released/):

> Note, there are several minor bugs
>   that I never fixed, mostly because
>   ext3cow more or less died off. If you
>   find a bug, let me know, I’ll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ask here, ext3cow-devel@hssl.cs.jhu.edu

Zachary posted there in March 2009, although that was one of the last updates to the list...

According to his web page, he's still a "lead developer",

http://hssl.cs.jhu.edu/~zachary/www/home.html